# ask a word from the console and print the index of each of its letters in the array

Tags: c#

I need to write a C# program that creates an array containing all letters from the alphabet and ask for a word from the console and print the index of each of its letters in the array.(I don't ask for the whole code I just need help on what should I do , thanks)

this what I did;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Letters
{
    public class letters
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int l = 0;

            string[] letters = new string[26] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };

            List<string> letterList = letters.ToList();

            Console.Write("Enter a word: ");
            string word = Console.ReadLine();

            while (l <= word.Length - 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(letterList.IndexOf(l)); l++;
            }

            

        }
    }
}
```

but I need output like this

Enter a word: word

w:23
o:14
r:18
d:3

Comment: So what's the actual problem? What EXACTLY does your code do that it shouldn't or not do that it should? It's for you to explain that to us, not for us to work out for ourselves. You should already know exactly what logic you're trying to implement so, if you don't, you should go away and work that out first. If you can't perform the process by hand then you shouldn't be writing any code yet anyway and if you can do it by hand then you should know exactly what logic the code needs to implement.

Comment: If you have a string like `"word"`, you can iterate over it with `foreach` much like can an array of `char`.  It looks a lot like `{ 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd' }`.  Then, as an experiment, try doing this `var someChar = 'w';` and `var index = someChar - 'a';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

close - heres a corrected and simplified version

```
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        int l = 0;

        char[] letters = new char[26] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };



        Console.Write("Enter a word: ");
        string word = Console.ReadLine();

        foreach(char ch in word) {
            Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(letters,ch) + 1); 
        }



    }
```

and just for fun, here is a one liner

```
Console.WriteLine(word.Select(ch => $"{ch}:{(Char.ToLower(ch) - 'a') + 1} ").Aggregate((a, b) => a + b));
```

using Flydogs calculation rather than a lookup table

Comment: Character subtraction wasn't good enough for you?  What about caps?

Comment: @Flydog57 - I kept the structure basically the same, I could have done a one liner LINQ solution if I wanted

Comment: you're awesome bro, once again thank you.